# How do I change the default English (United States) resource language in the MFC Application wizard?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, wizard

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Preview 2017 to build MFC Applications, and I cannot figure out a way to change the default English resource language in the wizard. I would like the strings in string table to appear in Portuguese when I start a project and I want that the message boxes to display everything in Portuguese, even the captions in the buttons that normally says "Yes" or "No".

I googled but did not find any result. I start a new project using the following steps:

1 - Open the New Project Dialog Box (**File > New project**);

2 - In the tree view I select **Installed > Visual C++ > MFC**;

3 - In the list I select **MFC Application** and click **OK** (this open a dialog box).

In the dialog box there is a combo box with name **resource language**. This combo box lists only **English (United States)**. Since this is a combo box I guess I can add more resource languages. I would like to add **Portuguese (Brazil)**, to be specific. But how do I do it?

I experimented to open **visual studio installer** and chose **language packs** and I checked **Portuguese (Brazil)** and then click on **Modify button**. After installation was complete I restarted Visual Studio and selected **Tools > Options > International Settings** then in the language combo box I select the installed language **Portuguese (Brazil)** and restarted visual studio, but this did not add the Portuguese language in the mentioned resource combo box. Instead, it changed the user interface language of visual studio.

So, What is the correct procedure?

Comment: In the menu, click "Project" -> "Properties". You should see `"Culture = English ..."` under "Resources" section. In new applications the program should be Unicode, and the resource flag is for keeping track of different resources.

Comment: I experimented, but it did not give the result I want. When I start a new project it continue to display English (United States). I would like that the strings in string table to display in Portuguese. For instance, ID_FILE_NEW  is displaying "Create a new document\nNew" but I want it to display in Portuguese. Also I want that the message boxes to display everything in Portuguese.

Comment: These are defined by MFC. You may have to add your own resource file. Look in this directory, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include"` you should find `"afxres.rc, afxprint.rc, afxribbon.rc..."` I didn't see Portuguese version. Maybe somebody else has done Portuguese, otherwise you have to translate the strings you want and use them instead of the English version.